# Select one column with same value and check another column's value

Tags: query, relational-division

I have a table with following structure (rest of the columns omitted for brevity) :

```
+------------+-------+
 | Cust_ID    | Status|
 +------------+-------+
 | 312        | A     |
 | 312        | D     |
 | 312        | D     |
 | 345        | A     |
 | 345        | D     |
 | 345        | A     |
 | 678        | D     |
 | 678        | D     |
 | 678        | D     |
 +------------+-------+
```

We can observe that same `Cust_ID`s have multiple `Status` in different rows. 
Now I want to pick `Cust_ID`s for which all `Status` row is `D`. So in the above case, the `Cust_ID` `678` should be listed.

Can anybody help me out in writing such query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I only use T-SQL, but I don't think anything used below is specific to SSMS:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Cust_ID
FROM Tbl t
WHERE
    Status = 'D'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE Status <> 'D' AND Cust_ID = t.Cust_ID)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select cust_ID 
from table 
group by cust_ID  
having max(status) = 'd' 
and min(status) = 'd'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called `Relational Division` and @Andy and @Paparazzi has given two solutions for it. Yet another variant is:

```
SELECT Cust_ID
FROM Tbl t 
GROUP BY Cust_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Status) 
     = COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN STATUS = 'D' THEN Status END)
```

Comment: Slightly shorter: `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE Status WHEN 'D' THEN Status END)` Much more succinct: `COUNT(DISTINCT IIF(Status='D',Status,NULL))`